# nodejs fs is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, brfs

I am trying to concatenate a bunch of files inside a folder using node's `fs`.

The problem is that I get a

> Uncaught ReferenceError: fs is not defined

When attempting to use `fs.readFileSync` with the `files` array in the code below.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var output = "";
var files = fs.readdirSync('./content');
console.log(files); //fs works here
for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i ++) {
  output += fs.readFileSync(path.join('./content', files[i]), 'utf8') + '\n';
}

module.exports = output;
```

At first I thought it was some kind of scope issue, but then I came across this issues [fs is not defined error when readFileSync is passed a path variable](https://github.com/substack/brfs/issues/36) which basically says:

> You can't use variables since the expression has to be statically analyzable, i.e. Known at build time, not run time.

So is there any other way to go about concatenating those files?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you using brfs or browserify?

Comment: The code you posted wouldn't produce such an error by itself.

Comment: @Matt , I believe its brfs.  There is both listed in the package.json file.  But the comments on the file I am editing suggest its a brfs module.  This is my first time looking at a node app so I am not sure how to tell. I forked [this](https://github.com/mapbox/docbox/blob/master/src/custom/content.js) but didn't want to have to modify the code every time I added a file.

Comment: @NickK. ok, that makes more sense then. Judging by that issue you are stuck with using statically configured files or doing the concatenation some other way, like a gulp task that runs before your app.